# Makefile - How to write makefile to get word in text

Tags: makefile, gnu

`text = bump(permission): nameservice - version v0.0.20`

Example, I have a string like the above `text` variable. I want to get a sub word from `text` such as:

1. word 1: `permission`, it is a word in pattern `bump(%s)`
2. word 2: `nameservice`, it is a word in pattern `: %s -`
3. word 3: `v0.0.20`, it is a word last of string.

I want to write a Makefile to get substring as required above. Please help me with this problem.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

GNU make has several [text processing functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) that can help. But as your problem is not completely specified it's difficult to propose solutions. I will assume that your text matches regular expression `^bump\((\S+)\): +(\S+) +-.* (\S+)$` and that the 3 words you are interested in are `\1`, `\2` and `\3`. If it is not the case, please edit your question and provide a complete specification.

```
text = bump(permission): nameservice - version v0.0.20
word1 := $(patsubst bump(%),%,$(word 1,$(text)))
word2 := $(word 2,$(text)))
word3 := $(lastword $(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) is, despite its name, also able to split strings in the way you want:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

text = bump(permission): nameservice - version v0.0.20

text_list = $(call glob-match,$(text),bump(*): * - version *)

$(info original text: <<$(text)>>)
$(info after glob-match: <<$(text_list)>>)
$(info specific parts: $(word 2,$(text_list)))
$(info $(word 4,$(text_list)))
$(info $(word 6,$(text_list)))
```

Output:

```
$ make
original text: <<bump(permission): nameservice - version v0.0.20>>
after glob-match: <<bump( permission ):§ nameservice §-§version§ v0.0.20>>
specific parts: permission
nameservice
v0.0.20
```

The `§` characters are space characters in the original string; the latter don't play well with GNUmake lists, so during internal operations they need to be kept replaced and in some circumstances it is best to even return them to the user in this form. Most of the time one can safely ignore them or you get rid of them with `$(call spc-unmask,...)` if they would get in the way later.